# POST requests test on JWT token returns "undefined"

Tags: reactjs, jwt, backend, token

I am very new to ReactJS, when I test GET requests for 'all posts' page after login (which creates the token in the first place), it works FINE but when I test POST requests to extract the token and use it in the 'add post' logic, it returns 'undefined' and 'HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized'.

I used HTTPie to run/test requests. I have been trying to fix this error for two days now. Please help.

```
export const login = (req,res)=>{
    const q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?"
    db.query(q, [req.body.username], (err,data) => {
        if(err) return res.status(500).json(err);
        if(data.length === 0) return res.status(404).json("User not found");
        const checkPassword = bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, data[0].password)
        if(!checkPassword) return res.status(400).json("wrong password or username")
        const token = jwt.sign({id:data[0].id}, "secretKey")
        const {password, ...others} = data[0]
        res.cookie("accessToken", token, {
            httpOnly: true,
            sameSite: "strict"
        }).status(200).json(others);
    })
}

export const addPost = (req,res) => {
        const token = req.cookies.accessToken;
        if(!token) return res.status(401).json("Not Logged In !!!");

        //if(!token) return res.status(401).json("Not logged in!");


    jwt.verify(token, "secretKey", (err, userInfo) => {
        if(err) return res.status(403).json("Token is not valid!")

        const q = "INSERT INTO posts (`desc`,`img`,`userId`,`createdAt`) VALUES (?)";
        const values = [
            req.body.desc,
            req.body.img,
            userInfo.id,
            moment(Date.now()).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
        ];
        
    
        db.query(q, [values], (err,data)=>{
            if(err) return res.status(500).json(err);
            return res.status(200).json("Post has been created");
        })

    });

   
}

import express from "express";
const app = express();
import userRoutes from "./routes/users.js";
import authRoutes from "./routes/auth.js";
import postRoutes from "./routes/posts.js";
import commentRoutes from "./routes/comments.js";
import likeRoutes from "./routes/likes.js";
import cors from "cors";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";


//middleware
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
next();
});
app.use(express.json())
app.use(
cors({
origin:"http://localhost:3000",
})
);
app.use(cookieParser())
```

Comment: May be server can't read token from cookie. Are you add cookie parse library in middleware.

Comment: yhh i did, i edited and added to post